# Which DAC is being used?

Tags: dac

If a Samsung 10 phone is connected to an aftermarket head unit in the car via USB-C from the head unit USB-A, which DAC is being used? A car audio forum says the phone DAC, but then that would mean analog was being used as an input to the head unit USB.

Answer (score 2):

USB Type-A has no analog lines, so unless this is a custom connector that only resembles USB, the phone's DAC is not used.

Typically phones support the USB audio device class and send PCM data to a DAC in the car stereo.

Comment: The phone can also show files which the car radio plays. In any case, no analog tranamission with the phone.

Comment: When you say "USB Type-A has no analog lines"  you mean that because the phone's usb-c connects directly to the head unit's type A input, that the data has to be digital, correct? Also, what do you mean by "the phone can also show files which the car radio plays"?. Show them where? You mean the audio application showing on the phone screen which file is being played ? Or, you mean the head unit shows what file is being transmitted ftom the phone to the head unit? Thank you for your insights.